# JavaScript file scanning: get int at certain line

Tags: javascript, string

I have a file that looks like this on my server:

```
0 2
1 8
2 3
3 1
//...
```

I already know how to get the contents of the file, I do it like this:

```
    var file = 'fileName';
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.open("GET", file, true);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if(rawFile.readyState === 4)
        {
            if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0)
            {
                var allText = rawFile.responseText;
            }
        }
    }
    rawFile.send(null);
```

The integer on the left in the file increments for each entry, the integer on the right is random. My program specifies an int n and I want to retrieve the value to the right of the left-hand value that is equal to n. In the example, if program specifies n = 2, I want to get 3. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The more traditional approach of searching line by line

```
var n = '2', l;

var file = 'fileName';
var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
rawFile.open("GET", file, true);
rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
{
    if(rawFile.readyState === 4)
    {
        if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0)
        {
            var allText = rawFile.responseText,
                lines   = allText.split("\n"),
                line;

            for (var i=0; i<lines.length; i++) {
                if (lines[i].indexOf(n) === 0) {
                    line = lines[i];
                    break;
                }
            }

            var numbs = line.split(/\s+/);

            l = numbs[1];
        }
    }
}
rawFile.send(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be:

```
var n = 2;
var right = allText.match(new RegExp('^' + n + ' (\\d+)$', 'm'))[1];
```